# How to pass datatable to aspx boundedcolumn datagrid

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagrid

Hello after having spent two days looking for a solution for this problem I give up.

I need to point the contents of a datatable to an asp control: DataGrid

this is the controller:
[image]

And the code that should be filled is the following:
[image]

I would appreciate all the help you can give because when I run the code it does load the datagrid but creates 2 more columns, plus I have to hide the ID column because the user should not observe this.

Below you can see an image of the grid[image]

Comment: To Start with, please remove the images of the code have the code shared as snipped in the question itself.

Comment: Use `AutoGenerateColumns="false"` and `DataKeyField="ID"  in `<asp:DataGrid` and also remove the entire line of `<asp:BoundColumn HeaderText="ID"`

Comment: Also use `DataField="Meeting Type"` in <asp:BoundColumn HeaderText="Meeting Type"`

Comment: Great I appreciate this I changed as Chetan said and it works fine !!!